# Notifications never go away

Tags: 18.04, notification, notify-osd

Ever since last week notifications will show, but can't be hidden.

Notifications stay there forever obstructing part of the screen and can't be closed.

This happens for most notifications and the only thing that hides them is pressing `Alt+F2` then `restart`.

I really don't know what's caused this. This is what I've tried:

- `sudo apt-get install --reinstall notify-osd`
- Logging in and out.
- Multiple restarts.

I'm running: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

Any help is much appreciated.

Edit: **FIXED**

Turns out I had this extension installed that doesn't work on 18.04: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/708/panel-osd/

Using: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3649/notification-position/ instead works perfectly.

Comment: maybe a tweak could trigger something. like permanent notifications
https://extensions.gnome.org/#      https://github.com/bonzini/gnome-shell-permanent-notifications        "This is a Gnome Shell extension to show the notifications as long as you don't take any action on them. They will disappear when you click them or they hide when you hover over them."

Comment: @pierrely It's a good idea, though installing that extension hasn't fixed it :(

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu.com! In case you find an answer to help solve a problem don't forget to click either the grey ☑ or the up-pointing arrow/triangle to the left of the text.

Comment: at your own risk but there are other notifications tweaks there you might try

Comment: new tweak https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3795/notification-timeout/

Comment: or put it out of the way      https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3649/notification-position/

Comment: @pierrely Thank you! Turns out this extension I had installed was causing the problem: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/708/panel-osd/ I tried the Notification Position extension you recommended instead and it works perfectly! It looks like Panel OSD doesn't work on 18.04. You have the bounty if you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the OP [Panel OSD](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/708/panel-osd/) doesn't work on Ubuntu 18.04.

Use [Notification Position](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3649/notification-position/) Gnome Tweak instead.

Comment: Thank you, my last edit to your answer was rejected, can you add something saying Panel OSD doesn't work on Ubuntu 18.04? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, that's good, can you approve my edit though? That's all I need.

Comment: I've suggested an edit to your answer, can you approve it? https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/1102784

Answer (score 14):

I got this issue on Ubuntu 22.04.1. How I fix that is simply lock my screen and re-login.

[image: Ubuntu 22.04 Lock Screen]

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1254672)

Answer (score 0):

(20.04) System Settings > Notifications >

`(__*) Lock screen notifications` <- is probably like that.
`(__*) Do not disturb`  <- if set, will not display any notfications.

... this might look differently in 18.04 *[ I have no way to check ]*

Comment: I don't have that toggle and I still want to get notifications, it's just the notifications don't go away

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: What you're suggesting would stop any notification from showing, **I still want notifications**. The problem's that something's wrong with the notifications and they won't go away.

Comment: **CLARIFICATION:** It is your **FREE choice** to NOT use "Do not disturb". I see the text here as more generally applicable than "only" answering your question.

Comment: Ah okay I see now, that's okay